# Inclusion Exclusion Principle for Calculating Probability of Unions

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose I have an std::vector containing 2 or more elements.  Now suppose I want to apply the inclusion exclusion principle to this vector (assuming, for example, its elements contain long doubles representing probabilities of events).  **In that situation, the goal would be for this function, when passed a vector with N elements, to apply the inclusion exclusion principle to find the probability of the occurrence of the union of all of those events.**

I assume that this may require some kind of template recursion, but I'm really struggling to calculate each the terms in the formula.  It seems like any time I try to create code that's generalized for any number of elements, it blows my mind and I get stuck or lost.  Does anybody have any advice to offer?

Comment: I think you seem to have a mathematical problem more than a programming issue here. Or can you at least write down a simple example?  Example data as input, calculations or sketch of calculations, and expected output.

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a more specific problem than 'it blows my mind and I get stuck or lost'? Ideally, share the code you've attempted. That way you can be pointed in specific directions.

Comment: Google gives me [this solution](https://e-maxx-eng.appspot.com/combinatorics/inclusion-exclusion.html).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't need inclusion/exlusion as long as all of the events are independent. If they aren't, [you need more data](https://e-maxx-eng.appspot.com/combinatorics/inclusion-exclusion.html).

The probability of all of the events happening are equal to their product.

```
float probability(std::vector <float> eventProbability) {
    float prob = 1.0f;
    for(auto &p: eventProbability) prob *= p;
    return prob;
}
```